# Why does pm2 watch restart over and over?

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I've been working with [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for a few weeks, using the `--watch` flag with no issues.

Then today, when launching even the most basic Node.js + Express.js app, it constantly reloads over and over, without end.

Command: `pm2 start server.js --watch` (results in pm2 id of `0`).

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server successfully started and listening at http://localhost:3000.');
});
```

I even using `pm2 stop 0 --watch`

---

On some occasions, I've noticed that even though the pm2 instance is stopped (and even deleted), the port remains open. So I've been using the terminal command `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` to list open ports, along with `sudo kill -9 PID` to kill the open port. No idea why that happens. Not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: have you try checking pm2 version? update it maybe. is there any other process write files to that directory or sth? editor auto save?

Comment: I've tried deleting pm2 and reinstalling it, and still the same. I do get a bunch of errors on pm2 install, such as `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make a processes.json and run it. update that with this option for running and watching:

```
//processes.json:
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name": "express-app",
    "script": "server.js",
    "watch": ["server.js"],
    "ignore_watch": ["node_modules"],
    "watch_options": {
      "usePolling": true,
      "alwaysStat": true,
      "useFsEvents": false
    },
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    }
  }]
}
```

Put that on the root of your project, then run your pm2 as so:

```
pm2 start processes.json
```

Comment: That works for then I do the initial `pm2 start processes.json`, but then when I stop that instance, and start it back up again, it doesn't restart on any change. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check if your app modifies a file in the project folder (such as a log file). A change to any of the files triggers restart if watch flag is enabled.

To prevent this, use a process file and add watch_ignore flag in it. Here's a documentation on how to use the process file : http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#process-file

Answer (score 0):

I was going crazy because I had tried everything to stop pm2 from watching a directory. At the end I just deleted the processes and started all over again. I think my mistake was that the first time I had `watch: "."` set as property in ecosystem.config.js. And I am guessing no matter what I did, that setting couldn't be changed. So as of now, this is my ecosystem.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'atelier',
    script: 'server/index.js',
    watch: false,
    ignore_watch: ["uploads/tempImage" ],
    instances: 'max',
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }]
};
```